# How to display and object relation when some records might not have its value associated yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to learn Rails and I don't know what's the best practices from the language yet.

I have scaffolded `Ticket` and `Status` models (a ticket has its current status). In my database I have records that has no Status associated to (`ticket.status` is `nil`), but I also have records that has a Status already associated (`ticket.status` has `#<Status>` object).

When I'm listing all tickets in a table (`/tickets` url) I'm listing the tickets and displaying the status name (`status.nome`) like this:

```
%td= ticket.status.nome
```

But I get an error when some records has no status associated: `undefined method 'nome' for nil:NilClass`

How should I proceed in this case?

--

## updated

`Ticket.all` gives me:

```
#<Ticket id: 5, titulo: "aeeee", descricao: "desc", user_id: nil, status_id: nil, created_at: "2015-09-11 07:01:38", updated_at: "2015-09-11 07:01:38">
#<Ticket id: 6, titulo: "teste", descricao: nil, user_id: nil, status_id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-11 07:09:45", updated_at: "2015-09-11 07:09:45">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) and it works like a charm.

In your `Ticket` model do:

```
delegate :nome, to: :status, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

and you can call it like

```
ticket.status_nome
```

Answer (score 1):

> undefined method 'nome' for nil:NilClass

For a quick solution, you can use [***try***](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
%td= ticket.status.try(:nome)
```

which will silence the error.